# JQuery 1 Click fires 2 conditions (if)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, onclick, document

```
$('.anfahrt').click(function() {
    $button = $(this);
    if ( clickedc == 0){
        if( !$button.hasClass( 'disabled' ) ) {
            $button.addClass( 'disabled' );
            clickedc = 1
            $('.lupe').animate({opacity: '0'},750)
            $('.card > img').animate({height: 150, width: 193, opacity: '1', left: 0, top: 9},500)
            $('.contact-content2').animate({opacity:'1'},500).animate({opacity: '0'},500)
            $('.cardgreen > img').animate({height:150, width: 193, opacity: '0'},500).animate({opacity: '1', top: 9},500,
            function() { $button.removeClass('disabled') }
            );
        } 
    }
});

$(document).(click(function() {
    $button = $(this);
    if ( clickedc == 1){
        if( !$button.hasClass( 'disabled' ) ) {
            $button.addClass( 'disabled' );
            clickedc = 0
            $('.cardgreen > img').animate({opacity: '0'},300).animate({height:0,width:0});
            $('.contact-content2').show(0).animate({opacity: '1'},300)
            $('.clickding').animate({width: '0', height: '0'},0)
            $('.card > img').animate({opacity: '1'},300)
                .animate({opacity: '0', width: 0, height: 0, left:194, top:75},270,
            function() { $button.removeClass('disabled') }
            );
        } 
    }
}));
```

So I click on the div.. and the animation start (fadein). Then it should stop... Then user clicks everywhere on the document and the 2nd animation (fadeout) should start. - But that does not work .. cause when I click the Div the fadein animation starts after that the 2nd animation starts right away. Theres no stop.. pls help me how to fix this.

Comment: Formatting your code a little more rigorously might help get your question answered. :)

Comment: there's a few ; missing here and there which won't help. also, clickedc doesn't actually get initialised anywhere, so anything could occur with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that the click event is bubbling up to the document level when you click the `div`.

What you want to use is the [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method on the event:

```
$("#yourdiv").click(function(event){
   alert("Your div clicked"); 
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Webkit and IE6 don't like event.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 1):

For the click event on the div do: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/. It will stop the event from bubbling up to the document level.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies in that fact that you're binding your
animations to click events all at once.  Thus, you click the div, it's
animation triggers, but at the same time you also triggered the click
event on `$(document)` and so that's why you notice the stacking
occurring.

To alleviate this, I moved the registration of the `.click()` event on
`$(document)` into the click event of the div and removed the need to
have the `clickc` flag as once the document's click event is triggered
it takes care of unbinding itself.

One problem that might arise with this approach is that if the user
clicks again the div the animation will all happen again.  But I leave
that to you as an exercise.

This solution is untested.

```
function open_animation () {
    $('.lupe').animate({opacity: '0'},750)
    $('.card > img').animate({height: 150, width: 193, opacity: '1', left: 0, top: 9},500)
    $('.contact-content2').animate({opacity:'1'},500).animate({opacity: '0'},500)
    $('.cardgreen > img').animate({height:150, width: 193, opacity: '0'},500).animate({opacity: '1', top: 9},500, function() { $button.removeClass('disabled') });
}

function close_animation () {
    $('.cardgreen > img').animate({opacity: '0'},300).animate({height:0,width:0});
    $('.contact-content2').show(0).animate({opacity: '1'},300)
    $('.clickding').animate({width: '0', height: '0'},0)
    $('.card > img').animate({opacity: '1'},300).animate({opacity: '0', width: 0, height: 0, left:194, top:75},270, function() { $button.removeClass('disabled')});
}

$('.anfahrt').click(function() {
    $button = $(this);
    if( !$button.hasClass( 'disabled' ) ) {
        $button.addClass( 'disabled' );
        open_animation()
        $(document).click(function() {
            $button = $('.anfahrt');
            if( !$button.hasClass( 'disabled' ) ) {
                $button.addClass( 'disabled' );
                close_animation();
                $(document).unbind('click');
            }
        });
    }
});
```